# Advice on multiple user Db for angular and laravel

Tags: php, angularjs, sql-server, laravel

I have an app with multiple users and they run reports on their account, all the reports gets generated into temp db, the problem I see with that is the temp report will overwrite the other persons report, what's the best way to have temp reports for each user?

1. Save it on local storage?
2. Make different table for each user?

What am I using:

- Laravel
- Angularjs
- SQL Server

What do you guys recommend?

Comment: Can't you just have a unique id, guid or similar so that the data will not get overwritten?

Comment: @JamesZ  lol I'm not going to lie, i'm so tired i can't think, that could be an approach.

Answer (score 0):

Set up your reports table so that you have user_id in there and all of the data for it. There's no need for a table for each user. Even if they generate a report twice or three times, you will have a record of each report for each user.

You can delete duplicates or not needed reports with a cron job on a [period of time] basis.